# Stop merge module from rebuilding when nothing has changed

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, windows-installer, merge-module

I have a solution that builds an .msi. That installer project depends on a merge module project which assembles various data files that need to be installed alongside the binaries. Even if I make no changes to the contents of the merge module, it insists on rebuilding (which is time consuming) every time I want to rebuild the binary + installer. I'm not seeing anything obvious in the project settings... how do I make the merge module package only if it has changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know, this is incredibly annoying. You can unload the merge module project (right-click it and select Unload Project), but that's the only way I found to deal with it.